# iOS NSDate get timeZone specific date?

Tags: ios, datetime, nsdateformatter

I'm getting time in `HH:mm:ss` format from web service and it is in Argentina(GMT-3) time zone. I want to convert this time into full date (dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss) and finally convert it into device local time zone's date.
Here is my code

```
-(NSString *)getLocalTimeStringFrom:(NSString *)sourceTime
{
    static NSDateFormatter* df = nil;
    static NSDateFormatter* df1 = nil;

    if (!df) {
        df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        df.dateFormat = @"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss";

    }
    if (!df1) {

        df1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        df1.dateFormat = @"dd-MM-yyyy";
    }
    NSTimeZone *sourceZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"ART"];
    [df setTimeZone: sourceZone];
    [df1 setTimeZone: sourceZone];

     NSString *artDate = [df1 stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]; // get 29-09-2015
    NSString* timeStamp = [artDate stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",sourceTime]]; // get 29-09-2015 00:05:00, if sourceTime is 00:05:00
    NSDate *art = [df dateFromString:timeStamp];
    NSLog(@"ART date %@" , art);//ART date 2015-09-29 03:05:00 +0000

    NSTimeZone *localTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    [df setTimeZone: localTimeZone];
  NSLog(@"Local date %@" , [df stringFromDate: art]);

    return [df stringFromDate: ds];
}
```

The problem is that i'm getting UTC date in `art` (as commented in code),please note that the value of `art` is 2015-09-29 03:05:00 +0000 which is in `UTC` and format is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`, but is should be in ART and d`d-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss`. I tried some code from net but didn't get solution. What is wrong in this code?

Comment: you say that web service format is HH:mm:ss while you are using dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss for it?!!!

Comment: please check i'm appending date into time as timeStamp string in my code. and this make it in dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss format

Answer (score 0):

**I use this:**

```
NSDateFormatter* serverDf = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[serverDf setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:-3*60*60]];
[serverDf setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate* gmtDate = [serverDf dateFromString:timeStamp];
//    DDLogVerbose(@"DateTime in GMT: %@", gmtDate);

NSDateFormatter* localDF = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[localDF setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
[localDF setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
NSString *localDate = [localDF stringFromDate:gmtDate];
```

Comment: give an example of input and expected output please. so I can compare it with the gmtDate

Comment: as mentioned in code above input is 00:05:00 (sourceTime) and final art date should be 29-09-2015 00:05:00

Comment: but i can't remove it because i want to check date-time in Argentina before convert it to device local time.

Comment: remove it for df not for df1

Comment: I think you are getting the right result and u shouldn't remove that line as I suggested. because NSDate is not related to NSDateFormatter at all. it always have the date in GMT. your solution is working already.

Comment: what is the locale of the device you are using?

Comment: what the method getLocalTimeStringFrom results?

Comment: art nsdate contains the right date. now you need it to be formatted for the device locale. which is done by your code in the last 2 lines. in short answer. there is nothing wrong with this code.

Answer (score 0):

May you just want a formate NSString , but not a NSDate,
Because I think NSDate will add a '+0000'

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this.
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
 NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:yourString];
 NSString *str = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: Does not make any difference. also can  you please add some explanation, so that one can understand your opinion.